# How to use a LaTeX package with R/exams?

Tags: r, latex, moodle, r-exams

I am using `exams2moodle()` to create exam quizzes. I would like to use some math symbols which require the LaTeX package `amssymb`. How should I proceed?

Comment: If you have a minimal example then it may help answer your follow-up questions in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: `amssymb` LaTeX symbols are supported by MathJax which is the default renderer in a standard Moodle installation. So these symbols should work out of the box when using `exams2moodle(..., converter = "pandoc-mathjax")` which is the default sinc R/exams 2.3.3 (released in July 2019).

Details: As already pointed out by the answer of @Hack-R, there are various ways of including mathematical notation written in LaTeX in HTML-based exercises. An overview is given in this blog post: http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/math/

It is important to note that in this case the LaTeX code is not actually processed by LaTeX itself. It can either be converted to MathML (using `pandoc` or `ttm`) or rendered in the browser by the MathJax JavaScript library. In any case it depends on the converter/renderer which LaTeX commands can be successfully displayed. All of them support basic LaTeX commands plus some extra commands from certain packages. Which additional commands from which packages are supported depends on the converter/renderer. In any case, the capabilities can *not* be extended by style files!

In a standard Moodle installation MathJax is enabled which suports the AMS LaTeX package (because MathJax was developed by/for the AMS!). So the best strategy is to simply keep the LaTeX in the HTML for Moodle. This can be done with `exams2moodle(..., converter = "pandoc-mathjax")` which is actually the default `converter` since R/exams 2.3.3 released in July 2019. In previous versions of R/exams, the default was `converter = "ttm"` which did *not* support all the `amssymb` symbols.

Comment: I used `exams2moodle(..., converter = "pandoc-mathjax")` and it worked! Thank you! I also realized that macroes cannot be used with R-exams. Is that correct? I was using `\def` inside the Rnw file and it worked with `exams2pdf()` but not with `exams2moodle()`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `exams2pdf()` is actually processed by LaTeX and you are able to do everything you usually do in LaTeX. But this does not apply to `exams2xyz()` functions that convert the LaTeX to HTML. There you need to keep the LaTeX code simple or produce dedicated images in LaTeX (e.g., via `include_tikz()`). BTW: Please accept the answer here on StackOverflow so it gets flagged correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you [input your symbols](http://www.r-exams.org/tutorials/math/) into either `.Rmd` or `.Rnw` and you can have it rendered with any available engine (e.g. pandoc, mathjax, knitr, etc).

```
install.packages("exams")

require(exams)
```

xWeave is called on each exercise file and creates LaTeX code

```
elearn_exam <- c("swisscapital.Rmd", "deriv.Rmd", "ttest.Rmd",
                 "boxplots.Rmd", "function.Rmd", "lm.Rmd", "fourfold2.Rmd")

set.seed(2020-04-16)
```

`exams2moodle()` produces an XML file that may be uploaded into Moodle

It goes from LaTeX to HTML then HTML to XML

```
exams2moodle(elearn_exam, n = 3, name = "R-exams")
```

To add custom LaTeX packages you can modify the preamble as per the answers in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown), i.e. `\usepackage`

As described in the linked post, that can either be done direct, i.e.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{mypackage}
output:
    pdf_document
---
```

or via a `mystyles.sty` file in the same directory.

Comment: I don't understand the preamble of which file I should change when using `exams2moodle()` and a Rnw file written with LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what R/exams does! However, the last bit about including a `\usepackage{}` statement in the preamble is _not_ correct for R/exams exercises. I'll explain why in a separate answer.

Comment: @user12703198 Just checking back on this. So typically you use `.Rmd` or `.Rnw` (and I'm only super familiar with the .Rmd way) to write the expressions which are later converted to LaTeX by a rendering engine (converter) and they have a YAML "preamble" at the top like this https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html where you can add packages as per the link. @AchimZeileis is saying it works differently with this package and I'm about to read his answer (thanks Achim)

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thanks; okay so if I understand you're saying it does work but it shouldn't be necessary if he uses the pandoc-mathjax converter because it should already work out of the box? But it looks like he is still not clear on this? Can you give him an example in your answer to help wrap this up?

Comment: The reason R/exams is different from `rmarkdown` is that we only use `knitr::knit()` to turn the .Rmd exercise into a plain .md file. But starting from there we provide our own workflow rather than relying on all the nice things `rmarkdown` can do. The main reason is that the text formatting has to be reasonably simple so that we can embed it into learning management systems like Moodle. And we want to refrain from taking image snapshots of rendered LaTeX - and we cannot include many JavaScript libraries etc.