# Using r-exams to include circuitikz package

Tags: markdown, moodle, r-exams

I want to generate electric circuit picture using circuitikz packages and r-exams in R markdown.
I already include circuitikz package in header-includes, it's successful when using `knit`

But when executing `exams2pdf` , here is the error i get,,

```
 LaTeX Error: Environment tikzpicture undefined.
```

Executing `exam2moodle` or `exam2html` get no error, but it did not include the circuit image

Any alternative solution?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? If so, please accept it but clicking the check mark below the note counter. If not, please refine the question so that we ca resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

### Why your attempts did not work

Additional LaTeX packages can not be included within the exercises themselves (e.g., YAML headers are ignored) for two reasons:

1. The exercises are processed with LaTeX only for certain interfaces (notably `exams2pdf` and `exams2nops`) but not for most others. In the latter case it is not straightforward to add further LaTeX packages.
2. Even when using `exams2pdf` or `exams2nops` exercises are only fragments of the LaTeX document that is eventually processed. Hence, there is relatively little that the individual exercise may control about the LaTeX document as a whole. (Hence, the YAML headers are not used for the indivual exercises.)

See also related discussions in:

- [How to use a LaTeX package with R/exams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256352/how-to-use-a-latex-package-with-r-exams)
- [Use isotope latex-package inside Rnw (r-exams)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61771771/use-isotope-latex-package-inside-rnw-r-exams)

### How to include TikZ graphics

When including TikZ graphics in R/exams exercises it is important to know what interfaces this exercise should work with. Some extra effort is needed to make an exercise feasible for all `exams2xyz` interfaces. Worked examples are included in:

- http://www.R-exams.org/templates/logic/
- http://www.R-exams.org/templates/automaton/

Both of these rely on the `include_tikz()` function from the package. This preprocesses the TikZ code via LaTeX and produces a suitable graphics format (PDF, PNG, or SVG) depending on the graphics format that is used for R graphics chunks as well via `match_exams_device()`.

Alternatively, you could also pass through the LaTeX code and assure that the necessary TikZ packages are loaded in the LaTeX template. In `exams2pdf` there is a `template =` argument and it is probably best to start out with copying and modifying one of the templates shipped with the package. See Section 3 in `vignette("exams", package = "exams")` and `exams_skeleton(write = "exams2pdf", ...)` should get you started with this. In `exams2nops` you can pass the necessary LaTeX code through the `header =` argument which is then inserted in the template that `exams2nops` uses.